# Using asset image as Tab icons in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, tabbar

I want to load images from my asset inside my `TabBar` in flutter. I have images in my asset folder as active and inactive. The images don't render well but i don't get any errors.

They just show as rectangular dark images. What am i doing wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Choice {
  final String title;
  final String image;

  Choice(this.title, this.image);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Choice> tabs = [
      Choice('Active', 'images/active.png'),
      Choice('Inactive', 'images/inactive.png'),
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: tabs.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: tabs
                  .map((Choice tab) => Tab(
                text: tab.title,
                icon: Image.asset(tab.image),
              ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Main.dart**

```
  TabBar(
                      isScrollable: true,
                      tabs: choices.map<Widget>((Choice choice) {
                        return new Tab(icon: new Image.asset(choice.image), text: choice.title);
                      }).toList(),
                      labelColor: Color(0xFF1C2447),
                    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use an `ImageIcon` for the use-case you described, you can use the `Image.asset` provider to get the image showing up in your Tabs.

For example:

```dart
new Tab(icon: new Image.asset(choice.icon.image), text: choice.title),
```

Here's a full example of it in action:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class Choice {
  final String title;
  final String image;

  Choice(this.title, this.image);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Choice> tabs = [
      Choice('Active', 'images/active.png'),
      Choice('Inactive', 'images/inactive.png'),
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: tabs.length,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: tabs
                  .map((Choice tab) => Tab(
                        text: tab.title,
                        icon: Image.asset(tab.image),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where should i place this?

Comment: In your main.dart file, inside the TabBar tabs property.

Comment: what am i changing in my choice class?

Comment: can you do a full example?

Comment: Added the full example to the original answer.

Comment: You can surround the `Image.asset` widget with a Container or SizedBox.